# How do I create a Dynamic Object with a ArrayList, which can use Methods?

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, methods

I got a Task for my education, and I need to program a delivery site.
I have classes called "Pizza", PizzaReader2 (because 1 was just a test) and the main class PizzaApplication.

So the PizzaReader works fine and it sends the information to PizzaApplication. There I want to create a dynamic object with the help of an ArrayList.
But I can't find a way to create a new Object AND use the Method from the Pizza class.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PizzaReader2 pzr = new PizzaReader2();
    ArrayList<String> a;
    String SplitBy = ";";
    int iCounter = 0;

    a = pzr.CSVRead();

    ArrayList<Pizza> pPizza = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String i : a)
    {
        String[] pizzen = i.split(SplitBy);
        int test = Integer.parseInt(pizzen[0]);

        pPizza.add(new Pizza());
        pPizza.set(iCounter, setNumber(2));

        ++iCounter;
    }
}
```

I just want to create a dynamic object with the params: Number, Description,
PriceSmall, PriceNormal, PriceBig, Picture(for now just a String).

Comment: You can pass all relevant info as constructor parameters. Or use a builder. Or do what answer below suggested and store new object in a variable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like following:

```java
int totalNumberOfPizzas = 10;
List<Pizza> pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
for (int number = 0; number < totalNumberOfPizzas; number++) {
    Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
    // Add Pizza Properties here  like pizza.setSize("LARGE");
    pizzas.add(pizza);
}

System.out.println("All pizzas are ready: " + pizzas);
```

Comment: Hello there,
first of all thanks for the fast answere, but I got a Question.
so far I gues it works, but how can I print just one specific Pizza, or two?

Comment: You can search around on how to print fetch data from ArrayList in Java.

Comment: Hello again, it works fine Right now, but I run it with the foreach loop.
But your way helped me a lot to get the Thing working thanks!